# Execute javascript in Cocoa using Javascriptcore

Tags: javascript, ios, cocoa, javascriptcore

I need to execute javascript code in my NSTextfield, which is something like this.

```
testStackData.projectServers.projectServerDefaultHeaders.push({"headerName":"name 1","headerValue":"value 1","trackHistory":1});
testStackData.projectServers.projectServerDefaultHeaders.push({"headerName":"name 2","headerValue":"value 2","trackHistory":0});
testStackData.stepError.haveError = false;
return testStackData;
```

Is it possible to execute this javascript with  Javascriptcore framework.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What kind of code do you want to execute? Also how is the NSTextField involved in executing the code, do you want to manipulate the control or have the javascript code come from that field?

Comment: I have  javascript code in my textfield

Comment: You need then a context to run the javascript code, you can create one with JSGlobalContextCreate(), and then execute your code with JSEvaluateScript().